# Why is Dafny thinking that this incorrect algorithm is correct?

Tags: dafny

The following array reversing code is "proven correct" with Dafny but it clearly isn't correct. What am I doing wrong?

A counter example is the array:

```
var a = new int[4] {1,3,5,7};
```

with the expected result `{7,5,3,1}` and the actual result `{1,3,3,1}`:

```
// A method reversing an array

predicate is_sint32(x : int) { -0x8000_0000 <= x < 0x8000_0000 }

newtype {:nativeType "int"} sint32 = x | -0x8000_0000 <= x < 0x8000_0000

method reverse(a: array<sint32>)
    requires is_sint32(a.Length)
    modifies a;
    ensures forall i :: 0 <= i < a.Length ==> a[i] == old(a)[a.Length - 1 - i];
{
    var i       := 0 as sint32;
    var aLength := a.Length as sint32;

    while i < aLength
        invariant 0 <= i && i <= aLength
        invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < i ==> a[k] == old(a)[aLength - 1 - k];
    {
        a[aLength - 1 - i] := a[i];

        i := i + 1;
    }
}
```

I found a solution inspired by the great answer from James Wilcox. Adding here for future reference:

```
method reverse(a: array<int>)
    modifies a;
    ensures forall i :: 0 < i < a.Length ==> a[i] == old(a[a.Length - 1 - i]);
{
    var i := 0;

    while i < a.Length / 2
        invariant 0 <= i <= a.Length / 2
        invariant forall k :: 0 < k < i ==> a[k] == old(a[a.Length - 1 - k])
        invariant forall k :: i <= k < a.Length - i ==> a[k] == old(a[k])
        invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < i ==> a[a.Length - 1 - k] == old(a[k])
    {
        var v0 := a[i];
        var v1 := a[a.Length - 1 - i];

        a[i]                := v1;
        a[a.Length - 1 - i] := v0;

        i := i + 1;
    }
}
```

And here is the solution using C# native types for optimum performance when generating C# code:

```
predicate is_sint32(x : int) { -0x8000_0000 <= x < 0x8000_0000 }

newtype {:nativeType "int"} sint32 = x : int | -0x8000_0000 <= x < 0x8000_0000

method reverse(a: array<sint32>)
    requires is_sint32(a.Length)
    modifies a;
    ensures forall i :: 0 < i < a.Length ==> a[i] == old(a[a.Length - 1 - i]);
{
    var aLength     := a.Length as sint32;
    var aLengthDiv2 := aLength / 2;
    var i           := 0 as sint32;

    while i < aLengthDiv2
        invariant 0 <= i <= aLengthDiv2
        invariant forall k :: 0 < k < i ==> a[k] == old(a[aLength - 1 - k])
        invariant forall k :: i <= k < aLength - i ==> a[k] == old(a[k])
        invariant forall k :: 0 <= k < i ==> a[aLength - 1 - k] == old(a[k])
    {
        var v0 := a[i];
        var v1 := a[aLength - 1 - i];

        a[i]               := v1;
        a[aLength - 1 - i] := v0;

        i := i + 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is `old(a)[...]` does not mean what you think. See the [reference manual section on `old` expressions](https://dafny.org/dafny/DafnyRef/DafnyRef#sec-old-expression).

The short version is that `old` *only* affects "heap dereferences", which include field accesses (as in `old(x.f)`) and array accesses (as in `old(a[i])`).

Since your uses of `old` do not contain any field or array accesses inside the parentheses, they are not doing anything. Your postcondition is equivalent to:

```
ensures forall i :: 0 <= i < a.Length ==> a[i] == a[a.Length - 1 - i]
```

(simply deleting the `old`), which says that after this method runs, `a` is guaranteed to be a palindrome. Your code does satisfy this specification, but it's not the specification you intended to write.

Comment: And thanks again because it helped me find the solution => I learned a lot.